# Use camera and accelerometer to work like gyroscope

Tags: javascript, android, html5-canvas, android-camera, accelerometer

recently I installed [HomeTheaterVR](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blevok.HomeTheaterVR) on my android device ,
[image: img link on playstore]
in which i noticed this feature which uses camera and accelerometer to work like gyroscope. It is built with unity.

Im trying to replicate same feature with canvas and camera with js

i think it works by cropping the center of the captured image and finding it on the next image it captures, then subtract the new cropped image's location from previous cropped image location × -1 is the x axis, and y axis is captured with accelerometer.

i came over this [video](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=7Yvt45FJ3R4) on YouTube to this [repo](https://github.com/areai51/js-camera-motion-detect), motion detection using js canvas API

---

so is there any js framework which does this gyroscope like thing?

and if there i any helpful links to achive this, comment it

/ is there any better ways to achieve this other than crop and searching on canvas

Comment: For a high end system probably do-able in JS alone. JS framework is openCV.js but it will be slow (depending on setup). For high sample rate gyro you may have to use WebAsm. OpenCV is available in many languages.